# How to auto check all checkboxes with different name and different values?

Tags: java, javascript

Suppose I have a JSP page containing checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name=check<%=i%> value=<%= rs.getString("VDB") %>>
```

Here value of `i` depends on number of value retrieved from database.

I need a button to check all checkboxes.

I know how to check all checkboxes if **name of all checkboxes are same(For E.g: chk)** using:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function Check(chk) {
    if (document.vendorform.Check_All.value == "Check All") {
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = true;
        document.vendorform.Check_All.value = "UnCheck All";
    } else {    
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false;
        document.vendorform.Check_All.value = "Check All";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Any help in JavaScript only as I am not aware of JSTL,jQuery OR EL.

Comment: A selector for type = checkbox?

Comment: it's check1,check2..checkn depending on number of values retrieved from database

Comment: @GazWinter: no i have no idea of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain javascript have a look at the following link and see if that helps:

[Check all Checkboxes](http://3dmdesign.com/development/javascript-check-all-checkboxes)

It suggests the following:

```
function check_all_in_document(doc)
{
   var c = new Array();
   c = doc.getElementsByTagName('input');

   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
   {
       if (c[i].type == 'checkbox')
       {
           c[i].checked = true;
       }
   }
}
```

For jQuery you would simply need to use the `:checkbox selector` more information on that can be found here:

[jQuery Checkbox Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Comment: I would always go with jQuery for preference as its much easier than using plain javascript once you get your head around it.

Answer (score 1):

how about jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
     });
});
```

Comment: could u please share whole code as i dn't have much knowledge of jQuery

Comment: add this to your <head> tag
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
and then add the above code in <script> tags